# Solver used in libsvm

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I'm using *libsvm* in Matlab.

Could anyone tell me which solver is used by default in *libsvm*?

I'm using linear kernel and C-SVC.

From their FAQ(one guy there was asking how to switch to L2-loss - they suggested to modify the code) I think what they use is L2-regularization L1-loss. Is that correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look into the [implementation documentation](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) in chapter 4:

> This section discusses algorithms used in LIBSVM to solve dual
>   quadratic problems listed in Section 2. We split the discussion to two
>   parts. The first part considers optimization problems with one linear
>   constraint, while the second part checks those with two linear
>   constraints. [...]